# How would I use a variable from another method in a new method?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ATM {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String ATM;
    ATM myATM = new ATM();
    myATM.go();
    ifStatement();
    //Main method, declares variables and calls the go() and ifStatement() methds.
 }

 public void go() throws Exception {
    int balance;
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome to online ATM banking\nHow much do you want in your bank account?\nEnter your number");

    balance = userInput.nextInt();

    //Starts the program and sets a value to the variable "balance".
 }

  public static void ifStatement() throws Exception {

      //Creats if statements that change the outcome of the program depending on what the user as inputte dinto thto the program.
      //This has been done using int variables whihc have been converted into strings so that they can communicate wiht the userOption variable, the userOption variable's value has been set to whatever the user inputs int the program.

     String Withdraw;
     String Deposit;
     String Inquire;
     String Quit;
     String usersOption;
     int a = 1;
     int b = 2;
     int c = 3;
     int d = 4;
     String s = Integer.toString(a);
     String ss = Integer.toString(b);
     String sss = Integer.toString(c);
     String ssss = Integer.toString(d);
     //Declares variables

     Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); // Allows user input.

     System.out.println("What do you want to do?\n1.Withdraw\n2.Deposit\n3.Inquire\n4.Quit\nEnter your number");

     usersOption = userInput.nextLine();//Sets user input to a variable called userOption.

     if (usersOption.equals(s)){
        System.out.println("*****************************************\n                Withdrawl\n*****************************************\nHow much would you like to draw?\nEnter your number");
        String withdrawl;
        withdrawl = userInput.nextLine();
        balance = balance - withdrawl;
     }
     else {
        System.out.println();
     }
     if(usersOption.equals(ss)) {
        System.out.println("*****************************************\n                 Deposit\n*****************************************\nHow much do you want to deposit?");
        userInput.nextLine();  }else {System.out.println();
     }
     if(usersOption.equals(sss))   {
        System.out.println("*****************************************\n                 Your balance is 100\n*****************************************");
     }  
     else {
        System.out.println();
     }
     if(usersOption.equals(ssss))   
     {
        System.out.println("*****************************************\n                 Goodbye!\n*****************************************");
        System.exit(0); }else {System.out.println();}
    }
}
```

I declared the balance variable in the go() method and now I am trying to store that variable's value in one of my if statements. However, the compiler is telling me that it does not recognize the variable balance. Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You don't do that. You cant access variables form other methods. Instead: if you have things that more than method needs; then you use a  **field** within your class. But: this is **super super basic** stuff. Please read some good/book tutorial ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ ) instead of putting up such things here! Besides: you want us to spend our time to help you, so you please spend the time to properly indent/format your input.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry, I am very much new to java and programming in general (a matter of days) so it's not as if I didn't want to properly indent/format my input it's just that I wasn't sure how to as I'm still learning the basics.

Answer (score 1):

Just give your balance back from go and give it to ifStatements() as parameter.

Like this `go()` will return u an integer.

```
 public int go() throws Exception {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome to online ATM banking\nHow much do you want in your bank account?\nEnter your number");

    return userInput.nextInt();
 }
```

Like that you can give your `ifStatements()` a parameter:

```
  public void ifStatement(int balance) throws Exception {

      //Creats if statements that change the outcome of the program depending on what the user as inputte dinto thto the program.
      //This has been done using int variables whihc have been converted into strings so that they can communicate wiht the userOption variable, the userOption variable's value has been set to whatever the user inputs int the program.

  String Withdraw;
  String Deposit;
  String Inquire;
  String Quit;
  String usersOption;
  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  int c = 3;
  int d = 4;
  String s = Integer.toString(a);
  String ss = Integer.toString(b);
  String sss = Integer.toString(c);
  String ssss = Integer.toString(d);
  //Declares variables

  Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); // Allows user input.

  System.out.println("What do you want to do?\n1.Withdraw\n2.Deposit\n3.Inquire\n4.Quit\nEnter your number");

  usersOption = userInput.nextLine();//Sets user input to a variable called userOption.

  if (usersOption.equals(s)){
      System.out.println("*****************************************\n                 Withdrawl\n*****************************************\nHow much would you like to draw?\nEnter your number");
  String withdrawl;
  withdrawl = userInput.nextLine();
  balance = balance - withdrawl;
  }else {System.out.println();}
  if   (usersOption.equals(ss)) {
      System.out.println("*****************************************\n                 Deposit\n*****************************************\nHow much do you want to deposit?");
  userInput.nextLine();  }else {System.out.println();}
  if   (usersOption.equals(sss))   {
      System.out.println("*****************************************\n                 Your balance is 100\n*****************************************");
  }else {System.out.println();}
  if   (usersOption.equals(ssss))   {
      System.out.println("*****************************************\n                 Goodbye!\n*****************************************");
  System.exit(0); }else {System.out.println();}
    }
```

Than you could call it like that:

```
myATM.ifStatement(myATM.go());
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting that error is because you are declaring "balance" inside the go() method.

You can set this variable like input in your ifStatement(int balance) or you can define it at the begining of the class.